# Комментарии. Не нужны даже для документации?

Tags: любой-язык, code-style, комментарии, чистый-код

Роберт Мартин в книге "Чистый код" пишет

> А теперь рассмотрим легион бесполезных, избыточных комментариев
> Javadoc из листинга 4.2, позаимствованных из Tomcat. Эти комментарии
> только загромождают код и скрывают его смысл. Никакой пользы для
> документирования от них нет. Что еще хуже, я привел только несколько
> начальных комментариев — в этом модуле их намного больше.

```
public abstract class ContainerBase
 implements Container, Lifecycle, Pipeline,
 MBeanRegistration, Serializable {
 /**
 * Задержка процессора для этого компонента.
 */
 protected int backgroundProcessorDelay = -1;
 /**
 * Поддержка событий жизненного цикла для этого компонента.
 */
 protected LifecycleSupport lifecycle =
 new LifecycleSupport(this);
 /**
 * Слушатели контейнерных событий для этого контейнера.
 */
 protected ArrayList listeners = new ArrayList();
 /**
 * Реализация загрузчика, связанная с контейнером.
 */
 protected Loader loader = null;
 /**
 * Реализация журнального компонента, связанная с контейнером.
 */
 protected Log logger = null;
 /**
 * Имя журнального компонента.
 */
 protected String logName = null;
 /**
 * Реализация менеджера, связанная с контейнером.
 */
 protected Manager manager = null;
 /**
 * Кластер, связанный с контейнером.
 */
 protected Cluster cluster = null;
 /**
 * Удобочитаемое имя контейнера.
 */
 protected String name = null;
88
Плохие комментарии   89
 /**
 * Родительский контейнер, по отношению к которому
 * данный контейнер является дочерним.
 */
 protected Container parent = null;

 ... и т.д.
```

У меня два-три вопроса: получается что, если имена сами за себя говорят, то не надо комментировать, даже если это будет использоваться для доументации? Где логика?

И если имена сами за себя говорят и класс не для документации, то, получается, не надо писать комментарии?

Comment: Если не для документации (а в редких случаях и для доков), и комментарии не поясняют ничего толкового, а только расшифровывают название (которое и так понятно) — нет, в этом случае не нужно. В ином их всё же желательно оставлять, особенно если они описывают документацию.

Comment: Любые подобные книги не являются руководством к действию, считайте их лучше рекомендациями от автора. И относится к ним нужно соответственно. Иногда комментарии являются жизненно необходимыми. К примеру, если посмотрите в другие классы tomcat, которые посложнее и назначение полей/параметров методов в которых не настолько очевидные.

Comment: @AlexKrass то есть получается в случае с вышеприведённым примером разрабы tomcat погорячились и можно было просто перечислить поля?

Answer (score 4):

У любого комментария одна задача: сделать так, чтобы любой программист понял суть вашей программы, что и как она делает. Если какой-то кусок кода делает абсолютно очевидную вещь, то и комментировать ее ни к чему.
Нужно просто быть осторожным, ведь для вас, вовлеченного в программу на данный момент времени, очевидными могут быть и те моменты, которые другой кодер не поймет. Смотрите на код со стороны не замыленным глазом, и если потребуется лишнее время для понимания его работы, то ему определенно требуется комментарий.

Comment: Да, я понимаю всё это. Нужно где нужно и не нужно где не нужно) А вот пример из вопроса - не понимаю. При документации - для тех же свойств, наприме для поля name  комментарий "имя контейнера" не нужно или раз документация - то придётся даже такой коммент давать, потому что "правила хорошего тона для документации"?

Answer (score 3):

Наверное, я напишу примерно тоже, что написано в другом ответе, но всё-таки:

- Очевидные вещи комментировать не нужно:

  - Не нужно расшифровывать в комментариях "говорящие имена" полей, методов, классов и т.п.
  - Не нужно комментировать, что делает каждая строчка кода
- Что же тогда комментировать:

  - Код, который с виду не кажется логичным/правильным/уместным, если он так написан намеренно - самое то объяснить в комментарии, почему код именно такой, чтобы потом при рефакторинге в "нормальный код" не было сюрприза
  - Если есть какая-то внешняя документация по сложному классу/методу, то можно дать на неё ссылку в комментарии

Ну это так, вкратце.

Comment: Да, я понимаю всё это. Нужно где нужно и не нужно где не нужно) А вот пример из вопроса - не понимаю. При документации - для тех же свойств, наприме для поля name  комментарий "имя контейнера" не нужно или раз документация - то придётся даже такой коммент давать, потому что "правила хорошего тона для документации"?

Comment: @АндрейШишкин Нууу, если из этих комментариев автоматически генерится документация, то куда деваться. Но я писал бы кратко. Вместо " Реализация загрузчика, связанная с контейнером" писал бы просто "Загрузчик" и т.д.

Comment: "Нууу, если из этих комментариев автоматически генерится документация, то куда деваться" - вот, в этом и был основной вопрос) Чего тогда Мартин возмущался не ясно. Или он просто как пример привёл, а я подумал, что лучше никаких комментов чем такие даже если это документация

Comment: @АндрейШишкин Я просто не знаю по какому принципу Javadoc генерирует комментарии, возможно, если не написать никакого комментария там будет имя поля стоять, а оно "говорящее" и этого будет достаточно. В общем, надо у автора книги бы спросить, что он имел в виду, мы можем только гадать. Со своей колокольни я только вижу, что эти комментарии во-первых вода какая-то, а во-вторых возможно они и не нужны, поскольку они повторяют суть названия полей, только более пространно.

Comment: https://github.com/Oreste-Luci/apache-tomcat-8.0.26-src/blob/master/java/org/apache/catalina/core/ContainerBase.java  конкретно исхоник этого класса. Так что)  Спасибо за ответ. Сейчас ещё раз осмыслю - комментарии и ответы.